# Multiple issues with axes while implementing a Seq2Seq with attention in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk, sequence-to-sequence, attention-model

I'm trying to implement a Seq2Seq model with attention in CNTK, something very similar to [CNTK Tutorial 204](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.1/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb). However, several small differences lead to various issues and error messages, which I don't understand. There are many questions here, which are probably interconnected and all stem from some single thing I don't understand.

Note (in case it's important). My input data comes from `MinibatchSourceFromData`, created from NumPy arrays that fit in RAM, I don't store it in a CTF.

```
ins = C.sequence.input_variable(input_dim, name="in", sequence_axis=inAxis)
y = C.sequence.input_variable(label_dim, name="y", sequence_axis=outAxis)
```

Thus, the shapes are `[#, *](input_dim)` and `[#, *](label_dim)`.

**Question 1:** When I run the [CNTK 204 Tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.1/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb) and dump its graph into a `.dot` file using `cntk.logging.plot`, I see that its input shapes are `[#](-2,)`. How is this possible?

- Where did the sequence axis (`*`) disappear?
- How can a dimension be negative?

**Question 2:** In the same tutorial, we have `attention_axis = -3`. I don't understand this. In my model there are 2 dynamic axis and 1 static, so "third to last" axis would be `#`, the batch axis. But attention definitely shouldn't be computed over the batch axis.
I hoped that looking at the actual axes in the tutorial code would help me understand this, but the `[#](-2,)` issue above made this even more confusing.

Setting `attention_axis` to `-2` gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Times: The left operand 'Placeholder('stab_result', [#, outAxis], [128])'
              rank (1) must be >= #axes (2) being reduced over.
```

during creation of the training-time model:

```
def train_model(m):
    @C.Function
    def model(ins: InputSequence[Tensor[input_dim]],                  
              labels: OutputSequence[Tensor[label_dim]]):
        past_labels = Delay(initial_state=C.Constant(seq_start_encoding))(labels)
        return m(ins, past_labels)  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
    return model
```

where `stab_result` is a `Stabilizer` right before the final `Dense` layer in the decoder. I can see in the dot-file that there are spurious trailing dimensions of size 1 that appear in the middle of the `AttentionModel` implementation.

Setting `attention_axis` to `-1` gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Binary elementwise operation ElementTimes: Left operand 'Output('Block346442_Output_0', [#, outAxis], [64])'
              shape '[64]' is not compatible with right operand 
              'Output('attention_weights', [#, outAxis], [200])' shape '[200]'.
```

where 64 is my `attention_dim` and 200 is my `attention_span`. As I understand, the elementwise `*` inside the attention model definitely shouldn't be conflating these two together, therefore `-1` is definitely not the right axis here.

**Question 3:** Is my understanding above correct? What should be the right axis and why is it causing one of the two exceptions above?

Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some good news: A couple of things have been fixed in the AttentionModel in the latest master (will be generally available with CNTK 2.2 in a few days):

- You don't need to specify an `attention_span` or an `attention_axis`. If you don't specify them and leave them at their default values, the attention is computed over the whole sequence. In fact these arguments have been deprecated.
- If you do the above the 204 notebook runs 2x faster, so the 204 notebook does not use these arguments anymore
- A bug has been fixed in the AttentionModel and it now faithfully implements the Bahdanau et. al. paper.

Regarding your questions:

The dimension is not negative. We use certain negative numbers in various places to mean certain things: -1 is a dimension that will be inferred once based on the first minibatch, -2 is I think the shape of a placeholder, and -3 is a dimension that will be inferred with each minibatch (such as when you feed variable sized images to convolutions). I think if you print the graph after the first minibatch, you should see all shapes are concrete.

`attention_axis` is an implementation detail that should have been hidden. Basically `attention_axis=-3` will create a shape of (1, 1, 200), `attention_axis=-4` will create a shape of (1, 1, 1, 200) and so on. In general anything more than -3 is not guaranteed to work and anything less than -3 just adds more 1s without any clear benefit. The good news of course is that you can just ignore this argument in the latest master.

TL;DR: If you are in master (or starting with CNTK 2.2 in a few days) replace `AttentionModel(attention_dim, attention_span=200, attention_axis=-3)` with 
`AttentionModel(attention_dim)`. It is faster and does not contain confusing arguments. Starting from CNTK 2.2 the original API is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Nikos! Quick question: if I want to try this right now, and I don't want to build CNTK from source (yet), would copying the new Python implementation of `AttentionModel` suffice, or does it also require some recent fixes in the native code?

Comment: There were some bug fixes in native code. It would not suffice to copy the new implementation.